# How do you use a return method to convert integers into binary numbers?

Tags: methods, binary, return, drjava

I'm in my first year comp sci class and I'm using `Drjava`. I have an assignment to have the user input two numbers, both ranging from **0 to 255**, convert them to binary numbers, add these numbers, then output their binary version of the sum.

My program should include the following methods:

```
int[] convertToBinary(int b):
```

Translates the parameter to a binary value and returns it stored as an array of ints.

```
void printBin(int b[]):
```

Outputs the binary number stored in the array on one line.

```
int[] addBin(int a[], int b[]):
```

Adds the two binary numbers stored in the arrays, and returns the sum in a new array of ints.

I think I'm supposed to create an array of binary numbers but I'm not sure. If so, I can't figure out how to use arrays in return methods. Any idea on how to tackle this assignment? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you want to try SOMETHING and MAYBE it will work?  And if it doesn't, post that small portion; repeat until you have a fully functional homework answer...

Comment: Also from looking at your recent questions, please mark correct answers as solution for your issue so it can help others.

Comment: Note that an int is already a binary number on most hardware platforms.  It's not clear from your description whether what's wanted is a character representation of binary, or simply mapping the binary number into an array of some sort.  (And if an array, should it be an array of 0/1 values or something else?)  (And you return an array like you return any object in Java.)

Answer (score 1):

I havn't read your assignment but from the methods you provided you can most likely assume that you should store the binary numbers in arrays of size 8.

Hence 8 bits = 0-255.

To tackle the assignment try start by making a array and in some magical way converting the number into each bit b7 to b0.

Think of the array as in the following format:

```
[b7, b6, b5, b4, b3, b2, b1, b0]
```

Where bX is 0 or 1.

There are many ways of solving this problem, you could use the [toBinaryString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) method in the integer class and then parsing the text.

or you could make a simple solution with if statements and a loop.

Try creating some code and work your way around the problem and you should be able to solve it pretty fast the rest, adding two binary numbers etc should be easy once you managed to convert a integer to a int array.